# AngularJS $http.get function not executed second time

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement to create a multiselect dropdown using angularjs with values coming from database based on different parameters.I have implemented following code. It is working fine when the page loads at first time. If come to this page second time, the $http.get function is not executing and still showing the same data as in the first page load.
This is my .js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", ["angularjs-dropdown-multiselect"]);
app.controller("myController", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.AllDescriptions = [];
    $scope.DescriptionsSelected = [];

    $scope.dropdownSetting = {
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableHeight: '200px'
    };

        $http.get('/Areaname/ControllerName/MethodName').then(function (data) {         
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                $scope.AllDescriptions.push({ id: value, label: value });
            });
        });
}])
```

This is my html file :

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController" >
    <div class="container">
        <div id="divRight" style="min-height:5px;display: inline-block; width: 40%; vertical-align: top;">
            <label style="float:left;">Error Description : </label>
            <div style="float:left;width:200px;margin-left:10px" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" options="AllDescriptions" selected-model="DescriptionsSelected" checkboxes="true"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my .cs file :

```
 public JsonResult MethodName()
        {
            List<string> errorDescriptions = //Get from server
            return new JsonResult() { Data=errorDescriptions,JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
```

Kindly help me to execute this JSON method for every page request instead of only in the first page request. Thank you.

Comment: You say http.get() not called when you refresh web (like F5) or when you navigate between controllers (with $state.go)

Comment: I think issue is bcoz of caching. If there is no change in view, angular loads page from cache. So either check by clearing cache and you can also make cache false.

Comment: @Javierif : Its during both scenarios , the values are not getting refreshed. thank you

Comment: @Ved: Can you please guide me how to do it? I am new to this angularJS.Thank you

Comment: @ManojNayak in stateProvider add  cache: false

Comment: @Ved : Sorry I'm very new to angularJS. I have searched in Google but not getting proper way to implement. Can you please help me by providing sample code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with cache. Try to put your get method in variable (`$scope.GetDescriptions = function () { $http.get... }`) and use ng-init directive 
(`<div class="container" ng-init="GetDescriptions()">`). Also try to empty array before push elements in it (`$scope.AllDescriptions = [], $scope.AllDescriptions.push(...`)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $route.reload(), this reinitialise the controllers but not the services:

```
    app.controller("myController", ['$scope','$http','$route' function ($scope,$http,$route) {
    $route.reload(); // try pass parameter true to force
    $scope.AllDescriptions = [];
    $scope.DescriptionsSelected = [];

    $scope.dropdownSetting = {
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableHeight: '200px'
    };

        $http.get('/Areaname/ControllerName/MethodName').then(function (data) {         
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                $scope.AllDescriptions.push({ id: value, label: value });
            });
        });
}])
```

If you want to reset the whole state of your application you can use $window.location.reload(); instead route like:

```
    app.controller("myController", ['$scope','$http','$route' function ($scope,$http,$route) {
    $window.location.reload(); // try pass parameter true to force
    $scope.AllDescriptions = [];
    $scope.DescriptionsSelected = [];

    $scope.dropdownSetting = {
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableHeight: '200px'
    };

        $http.get('/Areaname/ControllerName/MethodName').then(function (data) {         
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                $scope.AllDescriptions.push({ id: value, label: value });
            });
        });
}])
```

Hope this works.

Comment: thanks for the solution.. But sorry its not helping me. 1st solution throws some error internally and dropdown is not populated with values. 2nd solution makes continues page reload without any stop.

Comment: ¿can you put some example in jsfiddle?